WebView continue to open browser instead of use app in-view
My objective is to make some apps that show already existing websites developed from me with html/js/php... I have started to read somethings on the web and i have developed the first app but seems is not possible to avoid the browser opening.. have try different methods but only 2 compiled and with the browser opening even on the emulator and even on my phone... next i post the code...
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
    webView.settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)

    //webView.webViewClient = CustomWebViewClient()
    //openUrl("http://www.example.com")
    //webView.loadUrl("www.example.com")
}

private fun openUrl(link: String) {
    val Uri = Uri.parse(link)
    val inte = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri)
    startActivity(inte)
} 

The first of the three commented lines came out with and error (inferred type)... the other 2 open browsers...

Have solved adding this "webView.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient())" and using the intent.
